# Smooth displacement on a plane with lowpoly holes

Tags: displacement

I have a plane with some lowpoly holes modeled in it. With the help of adaptive subdivision I want a clean displacement pattern on it. But no matter how I triangulate the model it will always show some edges. The triangulate modifier only makes it worse. Cutting quads inside the model is not an option here.

How can I achive a smooth displacement on a lowpoly plane?

[image: pic]

[image]